# PreparedStatement setNull in SELECT query

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am using Postgresql together with HikariCP and my query is something like

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE int_val = ? ...`

Now, I would like to set NULL value to my variables - I have tried

```
ps.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER); // ps is instance of PreparedStatement
try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
... // get result from resultset
}
```

Although I have rows matching the conditions ( NULL in column 'int_val'), I have not received any records..

The problem is (I think) in query produced by the Statement, looks like:

```
System.out.println(ps.toString());
// --> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE int_val = NULL ...
```

But the query should look like:

"SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE **int_val IS NULL** ..." - this query works

I need to use dynamically create PreparedStatements which will contain NULL values, so I cannot somehow easily bypass this.

I have tried creating connection without the HikariCP with the same result, so I thing the problem is in the postgresql driver? Or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Based on answer from @Vao Tsun I have set `transform_null_equals = on` in postgresql.conf , which started changing `val = null` --> `val is null` in 'simple' Statements, but NOT in PreparedStatements..

To summarize:

```
try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE int_val = NULL)){ 
  // query is replaced to '.. int_val IS NULL ..' and gets correct result
}

ps.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
  // Does not get replaced and does not get any result
}
```

I am using JVM version 1.8.0_121, the latest postgres driver (42.1.4), but I have also tried older driver (9.4.1212). Database version -- PostgreSQL 9.6.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just found a solution, which works the same for "values" and "NULLs" by using   `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` instead of `=`.

[More on postgresql wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Is_distinct_from)

Comment: That's cool, and then the only issue is I here functions in a unique constraint make the index not performant.  ie. when I coelesce(null, 'unknown') for a unique constraint.  I wish there was a way to have performant unique constraint with index as it is sooo typical to then query for those keys.

Answer (score 3):

It is meant behaviour that comparison x = null is equal to null (no matter what x is equal to). Basically for SQL `NULL` is `unknown`, not the actual value... To bypass it you can set `transform_null_equals` to `on` or `true`. Please checkout docs:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html

> Some applications might expect that expression = NULL returns true if
>   expression evaluates to the null value. It is highly recommended that
>   these applications be modified to comply with the SQL standard.
>   However, if that cannot be done the `transform_null_equals`
>   configuration variable is available. If it is enabled, PostgreSQL will
>   convert x = NULL clauses to x IS NULL.

Comment: "It is meant behaviour that comparison x = null is equal to null ".  if SQL NULL is 'unknown', why does SQL x = null not mean x = unknown while a null value in the column means 'unknown'?  I am sort of confused on that one statement @Vao Tsun .  Great answer though.  It's like null in SQL means unknown in a column value but means something different in an SQL where clause.

Comment: it does mean unknown. both column NULL is absence of value for the column and result of comparison.x= null means absence of value, thus unknown, thus in SQL null. NULL is always unknown, in where and in column. the trick here is that to check if column is null you should use `x IS null`, not `x=null`. because latter is always null, unless you trick the `transform_null_equals`

Answer (score 0):

It is important to recognize that `null` is not a value with SQL. It is encoding the logical notion of "*unknown*". This is why `null = var` results in `false` always, even for cases where `var` has a value of `null`. So even if if you are replacing the value of your variable (aka `?` in your case) with a value of `null`, the result be definition must not be what you do expect as long as SQL standard is complied with.

Now there are some databases around that try to outsmart SQL standard by assuming a column value of `null` should be taken as a programming language `null` (`nil`, `undef` or whatever is used for that purpose).
This creates some convenience for the unwary programmer, but in the long run causes grieve as soon as you need a true distinction between a  SQL `null` and a programming language `null`.

Nevertheless, for ease of porting from such databases to PostgresQL  (or simple for ease of lazy programming) you may resort to setting  `transform_null_equals`.

BUT, you are using prepared statements. As such, prepared statements are converted to query plan once and such query plan needs to be valid for all potential values of the variables used in the prepared statement query. Now, a `VAR is null` is fundamentally different from a `VAR = ?`. So there is no chance for the query parser, query optimizer or even query execution engine to dynamically rewrite the (already prepared) query based on the actual parameter values passed in.

From this, you should take the recommendation serious that is given with the documentation of `transform_null_equals` and change your code to use `VAR is null` when a null value is to be searched for and a `VAR = ?` for other cases.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you are telling me, that there is no way of using the same prepared statement for 'someValue's and nulls ? Which would mean that I need to generate a statement for every SELECT after I know the parameters (provided there might be null).. Well if there is no other way..

Comment: Exactly. At least when using prepared statements.

Comment: I would love SQL standard to allow DB's to have a switch where col = null MEANS col is unkown.  that sounds perfect.  I am not sure why the SQL spec doesn't allow col = null AND col is null both.  That would be super nice for tools and junior devs who typically start with col = variable (and that variable is null).  They expect to get results and don't notice and keep coding like things are working and we have to teach them this weird quirk EVERY time someone new joins.